# Location of Fullscreen Icon in Mavericks

Tags: macos

If anyone has a copy of 10.9, could you search system files for "fullscreen" or "tif" and post the location of "fullscreen-hover.tiff.."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Pacifist](https://www.charlessoft.com) and searching for "*fullscreen-hover*" in an **Install OS X Mavericks.app** *bundle*, I found **fullscreen-hover.tiff** located at:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QuickLookUI.framework/Versions/A/Resources/fullscreen-hover.tiff
```

Note that even thought I searched the installer bundle, nonetheless, the installed location should be the same.

Comment: Thanks so much! I hadn't thought of searching an installer.

Comment: The fullscreen resource used in the title bar is found at sArtFile.bin for those interested in theming 10.8 & 10.9.